# Pascal's triangle, simple or strong induction proof

Tags: number-theory

1) Prove that the $r$-th entry in the $n$-th row is $C(n, r)$.

2) Prove that the entries in the $n$-th row sum to $2^n$.

I know what the Pascal triangle is, but idk how to begin the problem.

Comment: Do you know how to structure a proof by induction?  Can you generate a formula for $r^{th}$ entry of the $n^{th}$ row of Pascals triangle?

Comment: no sorry, i can't do inductions very well. do you know where i can learn more about this subject?

Comment: Step 1.  Show that your proposition is true in some base case.
Step 2.  Assume your proposition is true in some abstract case P(n).
Step 3.  Show than when  P(n) it follows that P(n+1) is also true.

Comment: What definition of Pascal's Triangle are you working from?